# How to get values bound to a FixedSqlAction in Slick for unit test assertions?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, slick

I'd like to write better unit tests for Slick queries by testing that the correct values are bound in the right place.

Here's a simplified example of the type of method I'd like to test:

```scala
  def insertExample(
    key: String, name: String,
  ): FixedSqlAction[MyTableRow, NoStream, Effect.Write] = {
    (table returning table) += Tables.MyTableRow(key = key, name = name)
  }
```

And the unit test:

```scala
  "insertExample" should "return expected SQL" in {
    val context = mkContext

    val action = context.testClass.insertExample("some-key", "some name")

    val expectedSql = """insert into "my_table" ("key","name") values (?,?)"""


    action.statements.size mustBe 1
    action.statements.head mustEqual expectedSql
  }
```

I've been unable to find a way to see what the bound values are, all I can see is the sql with `?` placeholders.

How can I check which values are bound to make assertions in the unit test?